# Ftp/sftp server with user rights admin GUI

Tags: gui, ftp, sftp, centos-7

I'm looking for FTP/sFTP server for our web content maintainers to upload web content. I need ftps/sFTP support plus web interface for a user to grant rights to co-workers to update some folders under different directory paths. I searched for some time but in vain.  we're running centos 7.

Would anyone please help?

Thanks. /ST Wong

Comment: With SFTP you mean SCP (SSH compatible), or FTPS (Secure FTP)? Not using any myself, but [ProFTPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD) has several GUIs for administration. Also see [Wikipedia's comparison list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks,we target for scp.  we hope there is GUI for different web admin to dedicate access to web content folders for their team mates.

Comment: I am not aware of such servers that integrate all the features you requested in a single product for CentOS (or for Linux in general for what matters). There would be several options for Windows though.